# Vim ctags behaves strangely

Tags: vim, lua, ctags

I'm starting out Lua development, so I ran ctags on a simple starter project and tried jumping around the source code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>. Upon trying this, I got `E426: tag not found: cache_objects` where `cache_objects` was a function in another file. I checked the tags file and the correct entry was there for `cached_objects`. I also checked my tags path and it was correct.

I then tried explicitly executing the tags command: `:ta cache_objects`. This returned the same error. Now things are about to get weird. I executed: `:ta /cache_objects`, and it worked! It brought me to the function defined as:

```
function cache_objects (basedir)
    ...
```

I triple checked the spelling to make sure it was right. How could this be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in ctags. http://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/bugs/347/

If you noticed in your tags file that fields are tab delimited. However when ctags generated the cache_objects tag it included the space after it. vim only looks for complete words when using `<C-]>` which is why it didn't find the tag but did find it when you used a regex search. If you change the line to

```
function cache_objects(basedir)
```

it works.

Comment: That was it. Has Ctags development stalled? The last release was in 2009 and the svn repository hasn't had a commit in a while and still has a long list of bug fixes in the queue.

Comment: @cmtm the svn repository has commits from May 2014. Other than that I would say patching it yourself would probably be best. I don't know the state of the project.