# Inspecting lua with vim ctags

Tags: vim, lua, torch, ctags, exuberant-ctags

My symptom is identical to [Vim ctags behaves strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276918/vim-ctags-behaves-strangely)

Thus, I installed `universal-ctags` instead of old `exuberant-ctags`.
But it still doesn't work.

But there's little difference

no module functions ctags work with `<c-]>`:

```
function rmsprop(x, dx, lr, alpha, epsilon, state)
    if not state.m then
        state.m = x.new(#x):zero()
        state.tmp = x.new(#x)
    end 
    -- calculate new (leaky) mean squared values
    state.m:mul(alpha)
    state.m:addcmul(1.0-alpha, dx, dx) 
    -- perform update
    state.tmp:sqrt(state.m):add(epsilon)
    x:addcdiv(-lr, dx, state.tmp)
end
```

However, module functions doesn't work (with :) :

```
function DenseCapModel:setTestArgs(kwargs)
    self.nets.localization_layer:setTestArgs{
    nms_thresh = utils.getopt(kwargs, 'rpn_nms_thresh', 0.7),
    max_proposals = utils.getopt(kwargs, 'num_proposals', 1000)
    }
    self.opt.final_nms_thresh = utils.getopt(kwargs, 'final_nms_thresh', 0.3)
end
```

but with a bit of annoying, `:ta /setTestArgs` works.

I've been digging it for a long time, but not satisfied.
Also tried, 
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/vim-lua-and-ctags, which is not general case
https://github.com/XuJiandong/lua-ctags works just like ctags. `:ta /setTestArgs` is ok but `<c-]>`.

FYI, I am using vim to inspect TORCH7 code in server. Any alternative way to inspect torch code easier would be helpfurl. ZeroBrane Studio seems working in client.

Answer (score 1):

Seems no one is reproducible on my issue.
I just binded `<ctrl - \ >`  for such `/setTestArgs` tag.

included `map <C-\> :exec("tag /".expand("<cword>"))<CR>` in my `.vimrc`